Azure Devops // Service Connection // Terraform // Yaml Pipeline -> Build Error
I have setup a whole bunch of files for deploying a simple VM, but trying to use the ADO Service Connection setup in the projec, avoiding to hardcode secrets, however after multiple tries still failing
Error: Error building ARM Config: obtain subscription() from Azure CLI: parsing json result from the Azure CLI: waiting for the Azure CLI: exit status 1: ERROR: Please run 'az login' to setup account
I was hoping to pass values from the ADO Service Connection into variables extracted from the pipe yaml file to the main.tf terraform file for authentication
main.tf extract
provider "azurerm" {
features {}

client_id       = ARM_CLIENT_ID
client_secret   = ARM_CLIENT_SECRET
tenant_id       = ARM_TENANT_ID
subscription_id = ARM_CLIENT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
}

terraform-pipelines.yml extract
trigger:

- main

pool:
vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
KeyVault: "test-kv"
StorageAccount: "testtfstatedemostg"
ContainerName: "tfstate"
ResourceGroup: "test-rg"  
AzureRegion: "uksouth"  
vmCount: 1
vmNames: "vm01"
os_publisher: "Canonical"
os_offer: "UbuntuServer"
os_sku: "18.04-LTS"
os_version: "latest"

jobs:

- job: TerraformDeployment
  displayName: 'Terraform Deployment'
  steps:
  - task: UsePythonVersion@0
    inputs:
    versionSpec: '3.x'
    addToPath: true
    azureSubscription: "\<AzureDevops_Service_Connection_Name\>"
    scriptType: bash
    addSpnToEnvironment: true # this will add the required credentials to env vars
    useGlobalConfig: true
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
    echo "##vso\[task.setvariable variable=ARM_TENANT_ID;\]$tenantId"
    echo "##vso\[task.setvariable variable=ARM_CLIENT_ID;\]$servicePrincipalId"
    echo "##vso\[task.setvariable variable=ARM_CLIENT_SECRET;\]$servicePrincipalKey"
    echo "##vso\[task.setvariable variable=ARM_CLIENT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID;\]$subscriptionId"

  - script: |
    #Install Terraform
    curl -fsSL https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/hashicorp-archive-keyring.gpg
    echo "deb \[signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/hashicorp-archive-keyring.gpg\] https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com $(lsb_release -cs) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/hashicorp.list
    sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install terraform

    #Initialize Terraform
    cd $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
    terraform init


Do I need to pass az login nevertheless before running terraform init in the yaml? I am blocked any given help will be very much appreciated

your main.tf does not look like proper terraform ... I expected to see variables something like: client_id = var.ARM_CLIENT_ID

I think you should remove the \ chars from the echo "##vso.... commands

I  might need to add something to Terraform init as well

@HelderSepulveda Hi thanks for your reply, I am not trying to pass variables from a variables.ft file I am trying to extract the info from the ADO Service connection, but I can give it a try

@RuiJarimba I am not familiar with this approach so any advice is appreciated

You are using the wrong task to get the credentials. The UsePythonVersion@0 task does not have the options to receive ARM service connection and run script.
The correct task you should use is AzureCLI@2. See below sample as refence.
    steps:
    - task: AzureCLI@2
      displayName: 'Get login Credentials'
      inputs:
        addSpnToEnvironment: true
        azureSubscription: MyArmConnection
        scriptType: bash
        scriptLocation: inlineScript
        inlineScript: |
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_TENANT_ID]$tenantId"
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_CLIENT_ID]$servicePrincipalId" 
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_CLIENT_SECRET]$servicePrincipalKey"
    
    - bash: az login --service-principal --tenant $(ARM_TENANT_ID) --username $(ARM_CLIENT_ID) --password $(ARM_CLIENT_SECRET)
      displayName: 'Login Azure using az login'

Note:
This feature does not return the Azure Subscription Id.


I found a way to get it, and works // echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID]$(az account show --query id -o tsv)"

You don't need to set the authentication directly in your provider configuration:
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

After fetching the credentials from the service connection, you can set the corresponding environment variables used to authenticated to the provider at the task level, for all tasks that run terraform commands such as init, plan and apply - example:
  - script: |
      terraform init
    displayName: 'Run Terraform init'
    workingDirectory: ${{ parameters.workingDirectory }} # <------- set terraform working directory here
    env:
      ARM_CLIENT_ID: $(ARM_CLIENT_ID)
      ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: $(ARM_CLIENT_SECRET)
      ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: $(ARM_CLIENT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID)
      ARM_TENANT_ID: $(ARM_TENANT_ID)


working on your answer

@jma you might need to fix the task that fetches the credentials from the service connection - check the link in my answer.

I see all those in the documentation: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs#argument-reference ... it will work! ... but I just personally hate all those "magic" Environment Variables, much rather see them properly declared in a variables.tf and the vars set as the https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/config/environment-variables#tf_var_name

@HelderSepulveda I might be wrong but I always had the impression that using environment variables to authenticate to the providers is the recommended way. Don't you risk having sensitive information stored in the plan file if you use TF_VAR_name?

@ruijarimba the "" were added by stackoverflow formatting are not part of my pipe yml, however still having issues with formatting

@RuiJarimba we can set the sensitive on the variables: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/configuration-language/sensitive-variables to prevent that just that... Adding to my previous comment, the magic variables are not on all providers also there are no standards around this... @jma this is just my opinion, to me the practice of using TF_VAR_name variables makes the code cleaner and easier to understand, and is something that can be used anywhere

@HelderSepulveda from the article you mentioned: Terraform stores the state as plain text, including variable values, even if you have flagged them as sensitive. Terraform needs to store these values in your state so that it can tell if you have changed them since the last time you applied your configuration.. Using the predefined provider environment variables such as ARM_CLIENT_SECRET is the best option, IMO.

@RuiJarimba wow that is certainly a surprise, good to know, will follow that practice

Fixed the formatting issue, but still not joy, at the moment still stuck with issues, https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=900023%22%7D // https://github.com/jmlp1/JMA-AZURE/tree/main

@HelderSepulveda I fully agree with RuiJarimba therefore the changes I am trying to deploy using env variables and values extracted from the ADO Service Connection, should be easy but I am struggling. The alrterantive of using TF_VAR** invoke loads of security issues and possibly leaving traces of sensitive data behind

Finally passed the az login issue, still not init now with a different problem but getting there

You have missed adding the az cli task, to use your existing ARM service connection for authentication, avoiding the need of az login.
Using terraform task is another approach of having the same ARM service connection for terraform deployment.
then your jobs will look similar to this:
jobs:
- job: TerraformDeployment
  displayName: 'Terraform Deployment'
  steps:

  - task: TerraformInstaller@1
    displayName: 'Install Terraform'

# init command populated with backend details
  - task: TerraformCLI@0
    displayName: 'Terraform Init'
    inputs:
      command: 'init'
      workingDirectory: '$(TerraformDirectory)'
      backendType: 'azurerm'
      backendServiceArm: '<ARM_AzD_Service_Connection_Name>'
      backendAzureRmSubscriptionId: '$(ARM_SUBCRIPTION_ID)'
      backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: '$(TFSTATE_RG)'
      backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: '$(TFSTATE_SA)'
      backendAzureRmContainerName: '$(TFSTATE_CONTAINER)'
      backendAzureRmKey: '$(TFSTATE_KEY)'

# sample of other command e.g plan
  - task: TerraformCLI@0
    displayName: 'Terraform Plan'
    inputs:
      command: 'plan'
      workingDirectory: '$(TerraformDirectory)'
      environmentServiceName: '<AzureDevops_Service_Connection_Name>'
      providerAzureRmSubscriptionId: $(ARM_SUBCRIPTION_ID)
      commandOptions: -out=output.tfplan  # allow to pass more options

I noticed that the OS-related variables seem to be for Terraform configuration. They should be passed using the TF_VAR_ prefix to ensure Terraform recognizes them:
variables:
  TF_VAR_vm_count: 1
  TF_VAR_vm_names: "vm01"
  TF_VAR_os_publisher: "Canonical"
  TF_VAR_os_offer: "UbuntuServer"
  TF_VAR_os_sku: "18.04-LTS"
  TF_VAR_os_version: "latest"

You could as well refactored your terraform code to use a terraform variable file. If the file is named terraform.tfvars and is in your terraform working directory , it should be recognised by terraform by default.
vm_count = 1
vm_names = "vm01"
os_publisher = "Canonical"
os_offer = "UbuntuServer"
os_sku = "18.04-LTS"
os_version = "latest"


I have already a terraform.tfvars files those were refactored

You are quite on track, good job.
